# Sparx EA - Opportunity element

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm using Sparx's Enterprise Architect v10.0.1007

Is there an Opportunity element as I am wanting to capture a SWOT (Strengths, Weaknesses, Opportunities and Threats) analysis?
If so, where do I find it in the toolbox?

Comment: Nowhere. There is nothing along those lines in EA. You could create your own MDG for this purpose.

Comment: @ThomasKilian is absolutely right, so please add it as an answer. Even a simple "no" is an answer. :)

Comment: @Uffe Well, another answer just got a down vote because someone felt like seeing it as comment. There's obviously a thin line between answer and comment. Anyway, see below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere. There is nothing along those lines in EA. You could create your own MDG for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there isn't anything in the base functionality, but there is in the TOGAF MDG.  This is from the TOGAF help files.

[image: TOGAF help files for ADM:Goal]